# QGIS ShapeTools XY to line empty output

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, convert

I have a shapefile with 2 points.

I am using the `XY to Line` tool in the `ShapeTools` plugin to create a Geodesic, Great Circle, and Simple Line. However, in each case, the tool is running successfully, but producing empty outputs.

The following screenshots shows the parameters:

[image]

The straight line connecting the 2 points is getting successfully created if I use the `Points to Path` tool.

The aim of this exercise is to be able to see the difference in geodetic distance and Euclidean distance. I also want to show how the projection of the geodetic line connecting the two points look like on a flat map.

If I do not check the optional check boxes, `Use the point geometry for the line starting point` and `Use the point geometry for the line ending point`, the tool show the error `Please select valid starting and ending point columns`.

I am using QGIS 3.4.1

Comment: You seem to have checked both 'Use point geometry for the line starting/ending point'. Does your source layer contain point or line features? Or attributes for start/end points?

Comment: @FSimardGIS : My shapefile has just 2 points which are meant to be the start and end points. The order does not matter.

Comment: I believe this tool is meant to work with 1 feature > 1 line, not 2 features > 1 line. In other words, try to include all the info (start/end x/y fields) in one single record per line that you want to create.

Comment: @FSimardGIS: I understand that having both the start and the end point in the same column is possible when the data is in a table, but how is that permissible in a shapefile? The tool takes as input a shapefile.

Comment: The tool help states the following : '_One of the coordinates can be from a point layer geometry_', so I don't think it can work with 2. You can only use it for _one_ of the coordinates

Comment: @FSimardGIS: Your suggestion worked. I made a csv file with the start and end coordinate in the same row, imported that csv, and in the tool explicitly told which columns had the start and end coordinates. If you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have checked both 'Use point geometry for the line starting/ending point'. However, this tool is meant to work with 1 feature > 1 line, not 2 features > 1 line. Try to include all the info (start/end x/y fields) in one single record per line that you want to create.

The tool help states the following : '*One of the coordinates can be from a point layer geometry*', so you can only use a point geometry for one of the coordinates, and the other coordinate pair would have to be in 2 fields (x/y) in the table.

Comment: Adding text from previous comment here for clarity: Your suggestion worked. I made a csv file with the start and end coordinate in the same row, imported that csv, and in the tool explicitly told which columns had the start and end coordinates.